# What could make a function containing an insert query pass a null value

Tags: php, mysql

I'm very new to PHP and SQL.I'm building a small database that represents members of a gym.  I'm using the MVC pattern for the first time and running into an issue with my INSERT query.  I have a function in my model called add_member that gets variables via POST from a form. I have used var_dump to verify that all the data is being passed over from the form but when it enters the query, it won't populate the table.  I've tried setting the function to a variable and using var_dump on that and it shows that the variable contains a NULL value(not really sure if this is the correct way to check but if I am wrong any hints on how to check more efficiently would be appreciated).

I should also mention that there are 3 more columns in the database table.  One is ID which is auto-incremented, another one is Password, and final one is Admin which is set by me to true or false (for a login page)

**Here is my database connection**

```
 $db_host = 'mysql:dbname=gym_membership; host=localhost';
 $db_username = "root";
 $db_name = "gym_membership";

 try {
    $db = new PDO($db_host, $db_username);//tests connection
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM member_info';
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $user_inf = $statement->fetchAll();
    $statement->closeCursor();

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $error = $e->getMessage();//
    include('error.php');
    exit();
}
```

**This is the function contained in the model:**

```
function add_member($fname, $lname, $email, $address, $city, $state, $zipcode, $phone, $emergency, $gender,
                $medical, $ptrainer) {                                                                                             //zipcode may be zip-----took out ph
global $db;
$query = "INSERT INTO member_info 
                (fname, lname, email, address, city, state, zipcode, phone, emergency, gender,
                medical, ptrainer)
            VALUES
                (:fname, :lname, :email, :address, :city, :state, :zipcode, :phone, :emergency,
                 :gender, :medical, :ptrainer)";
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement -> bindValue(':fname', $fname);
    $statement -> bindValue(':lname', $lname);
    $statement -> bindValue(':email', $email);
    $statement -> bindValue(':address', $address);
    $statement -> bindValue(':city', $city);
    $statement -> bindValue(':state', $state);
    $statement -> bindValue(':zipcode', $zipcode);
    $statement -> bindValue(':phone', $phone);
    $statement -> bindValue(':emergency', $emergency);
    $statement -> bindValue(':gender', $gender);
    $statement -> bindValue(':medical', $medical);
    $statement -> bindValue(':ptrainer', $ptrainer);
    $statement -> execute();
    //$statement->closeCursor; --------------------This was causing errors


}
```

**Here is the function call from the controller**

```
 $action = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'action');

 if($action =='add_member'){
   $fname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'fname');
   $lname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'lname');
   $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email');
   $address = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'address');
   $city = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'city');
   $state = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'state');
   $zipcode = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'zipcode');
   $phone = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'phone');
   $emergency = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'emergency');
   $gender = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'gender');
   $medical = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'medical');
   $ptrainer = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ptrainer');


add_member($fname, $lname, $email, $address, $city, $state, $zipcode, $phone, $emergency, $gender, $medical, $ptrainer);

header('Location : ./main.php');

}
```

**Here is the Form that is passing the data over**

```
 <main>
    <h1>Add Member</h1>
    <form action="index.php" method="post" id="add_product_form">       <!--CHANGE ID WHEN I DO CSS -->
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add_member">

    <label>First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="fname" />
    <br>

    <label>Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="lname" />
    <br>

    <label>E-Mail:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" />
    <br>

    <label>Address:</label>
    <input type="text" name="address" />
    <br>

    <label>City:</label>
    <input type="text" name="city" />
    <br>

    <label>State:</label>
    <select name="state"> 
         <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
         <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
         <option value="DC">District of Columbia</option>
         <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
         <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
     </select>
    <br>            


    <label>Zip Code:</label>
    <input type="text" name="zipcode" />
    <br>

    <label>Phone:</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone" />
    <br>

    <label>Emergency:</label>
    <input type="text" name="emergency" />
    <br>

    <label>Gender:</label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value = "male" />Male
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value = "female" />Female
    <br>

    <label>Medical:</label>
    <input type="text" name="medical" />
    <br>

    <label>Sign Up for Personal Trainer:</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="ptrainer" value = "yes" />Yes!   <!--VALUE MAY NEED TO BE PUT IN CAPS-->
    <br>

    <label>&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" />
    <br>

</main>
```

Comment: what is `$action` ? also do a `var_dump` of your post. Also you may be using some sql reserved words. Also how do you know the function `add_member` executed successfully? Aren't you supposed to check for that?

Comment: $action is  a hidden <input> value that is passed over from the form  since it is being passed to a controller that calls multiple functions, it is used to tell the controller which function to call

Comment: please do post your html form as well

Comment: can you tell which field is showing null when you dump the values? or is null being passed in all the fields?